# why it is possible to get access to private field in static method if you pass object as parameter

Tags: java

For example I've got simple class

```
class Simple {
    private int i = 6;

    private static void method(Simple obj) {
        System.out.println("Value i: " + obj.i);
    }

    public void method() {
        method(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Simple().method();
    }
}
```

Why I can get access to `i` in static method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`private` [members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) can be accessible with in the class. Your static method belongs to the same class. Hence you can access.

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------

private     **Y**      N        N           N
```

**Update:** To avoid the confusion, move the static method to other class and try once.

Comment: But they're asking why, if `method()` is static but `i` is not, why `i` is accessible when `i` is objective.

Comment: @mr.stobbe Since you have the object in hand, you can access them.

Comment: But I get access without getter.

Comment: Yeah, was just writing a "oopps... see it now" comment when you commented.

Comment: @mr.stobbe they are using i with obj which they passes with the method.

Comment: @user1432980: Right: The static member is still code in the class, and so it has access to private class information. The fact that it's static and not an instance member is completely irrelevant. The privacy relates to whether the code is part of the class, not whether it's *instance* code in the class.

Comment: Upvoted as the correct answer. But you might want to flush it out stating that access scope is independent of object scope in this regard allowing the property to be accessed when the object is passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused with `static` and `private/public/[default]`. Those are two separate things. A `static` function can access `private` non-static field because it is part of the `class`. And thats whats `private` does, only restricting access to the `class` level, without any distinction being made between `static` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the staticness that's bothering you, obj is a proper "not static" object, which us why it has an accessible non-static field. The *method* being static is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

you are accessing instance of object not directly class variable. when you use direly "i" without reference to object its not allowed.

Private variable visibility is by default in with in class access .

```
public class Simple {   

private int i = 6;

private static void method(Simple obj) {
    System.out.println("Value i: " + i);  //compile Error ::Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field i
}
public void method() {
    method(this);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Simple().method();
}

}
```